# Ada - constraint error

Tags: ada

I can't figure out why the code below is failing.  I have my own version of the same script which returns the same error. I can't figure out in either case why the error persists.

This is the error:

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : main2.adb:32 index check failed
```

which is this line:

```
temp(i) := a(loop_high);
```

Anyone know what may be causing this?

```
with Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure main2 is

use Text_IO;
use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

type int_array is array(1..5) of integer;
tosort:int_array;


procedure merge (a:in out int_array; low,mid,high:in integer) is
   temp: int_array;
   choose1: boolean;
   loop_low,loop_high:integer;

begin
   loop_low:=low;
   loop_high:=high;

   for i in low..high loop

      if (loop_low>mid) then choose1:=false;
      elsif (loop_high>high) then choose1:=true;
      else  choose1:= a(loop_low)<a(loop_high);
      end if;           -- choose which side

      if choose1 then       -- choose from low side
          temp(i):=a(loop_low);
          loop_low:=loop_low+1;
      else
          temp(i):=a(loop_high);    -- choose from high side
          loop_high:=loop_high+1;
      end if;
   end loop;
   a:=temp;
end merge;

procedure mergesort(a: in out int_array;low,high:integer) is
   mid:integer;
begin
   if low<high then
     mid:= (high+low)/2;
     mergesort(a,low,mid);
     mergesort(a,mid+1,high);
     merge(a,low,mid,high);
   end if;
end mergesort;

begin
   tosort := (171, 201, 397, 10, -381);
   mergesort(tosort,1,5);
end main2;
```

Comment: Either `i` is outside `temp'range`, or `loop_high` is outside `a'range`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused since the above is not my code.  I just edited it and expected it to run properly.   In my code, I get the same error around the same area

[Link to original code](http://www.ada95.ch/doc/tut1/Recursion/merge_sort.html)

Comment: Yes the original code is buggy. You might want to tell the author about that; there's an e-mail address at the bottom of the web page.

Comment: ha ok.  I guess I was hoping that it could be some other reason

Comment: If I understand, when you call `merge`, your array is segmented into two parts, both sorted, and you are merging them and leaving the merged result in the array.  I'm sorry, but I don't think it's possible to do an "in-place merge" like that without shifting sequences of elements over, which I think means it's no longer an _O(n)_ algorithm.  (See http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/AdvSorting/MergeSorts/InPlace.html.)  You need to create a new array to hold the merged results, then copy it back.

Comment: I actually use two temp arrays in my own code.  I thought the fact that the code from online hitting the same error could be a similar reason other than some array out of bounds error.  Probably a silly thought but I also figured if someone posted something online that it would work

Comment: The problem that leads to the constraint error is all the unguarded increments of index variables: `loop_high:=loop_high+1;` for example.

Comment: @AndD sounds a little like the woman in this commercial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bufTna0WArc (p.s. no, I don't mean to say your thought was _that_ silly)

Comment: Hah no worries.  In retrospect I think it was.  I sat down and worked through the algorithm and caught why it was out of bounds.  I was pretty sure it was fine but obviously wasn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend compiling with -gnateE, which will give you more information for compiler-generated exceptions. In this specific case, it should tell you which value is outside of which range

Comment: Good tip. In this case, it says `raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : andd.adb:33:22 index check failed` and `index 6 not in 1..5`; `33:22` means column 22 of line 33, and it’s `loop_high` that’s the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  Is it just gnatmake -gnatE main2?  I tried that but same result

Comment: I do understand now why it's failing so appreciate the help guys!  I didn't take into account the increments of the index which would quickly lead to trying to access something outside of the array.  It would be great to know what I'm doing wrong when compiling though to get that info you guys mention.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the .o and .ali first, and then recompiling. It is likely that your files were already compiled. An alternative is to compile with -s to recompile when the compiler switches are changed

Comment: Ah ok.  I had a minor change to one of the files and assumed it would recompile everything.  I'll try that later.

Comment: `gnatmake -f` recompiles everything, though you shouldn’t need it normally (GNAT is very good at working out dependencies). And the answer recommends `-gnateE` - not just `-gnatE`, which means something entirely different! Try `gnatmake -h` and be amazed.

Comment: Oops!! I didn't notice the extra e. Thanks! I also got my program working after the help you guys provided so thanks everyone